# Clean $_POST as $_POST or as a different variable

Tags: php, security, post

I'm mailing form input with PHP.

Should I do:

```
$_POST['whatever'] = function_to_remove_control_characters($_POST['whatever']);
```

or

```
$whatever = function_to_remove_control_characters($_POST['whatever']);
```

at the beginning of my script?

Why?

(I'm further filtering and/or escaping before the input gets sent by mail or output to HTML.)

Comment: First one will be okk

Comment: You shouldn't manipulate the $_POST like that... assign to the variable $whatever, like in the second case.

Comment: $whatever = function_to_remove_control_characters($_POST['whatever']);

Comment: Because it is not safe, it could lead to misunderstandings, and because superglobals (automatic globals) are not ment to be handled that way.  There are also some restriction using them as variable variables inside functions and methods. (http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)

Comment: @Masiorama I cannot think of a single reason why you'd want to use `$_POST` as a variable variable. But then, I can think of vanishingly few sensible uses for variable variables *ever*.

Comment: @IMSoP I just mentioned because it is documented, not because I'm a big fun of variable variables ;)

Answer (score 6):

It's important to remember that there is no such thing as "escaping everything" in a string, different contexts require different escapes. So the function to escape a string for use in SQL is different from the one to escape it for use in HTML, or for use in an e-mail body.

Your escaping should therefore happen *as late as possible*, where you are using text *for a particular purpose*, rather than as soon as you receive input from a user. Similarly, you don't want to overwrite the same variable with different escaping applied - for instance, you might want to use it in an HTML template and a plain-text e-mail, so would want `htmlspecialchars()` applied in one place and not the other.

This leads to the second approach, with a local variable, being the better one, as overwriting `$_POST` means making a global change to the user's input, which might be inappropriate elsewhere in your code.

There may be cases where you want to sanitise (e.g. trim whitespace, strip rather than escape forbidden characters) and then use in multiple contexts, but it is still clearest if you do this using a new variable, so you can track which changes have been applied. That way, `$_POST` always represents exactly what the user actually submitted, not what you wanted them to submit.

Comment: Thank you, @IMSoP. I read here on SO that while, as you say, one should escape as late as possible, one should also clean out control characters as early as possible. This was said without explanation (but upvoted a lot of times), so I thought to implement it. I don't see what I would use the original input for, if it contains those malignant characters (I'm not stripping anything else). Could you explain?

Comment: @what Hm, I can't really answer to why other people advised that without seeing the context (and possibly asking them). To me, there's not really such a thing as a "malignant character" - while unlikely, you might have some use for POSTing binary data, and in that case you wouldn't want your automatic filter messing with it.

Answer (score 1):

Both won't produce error both are okay. But second one is more clear.

`$_POST` is supergrobal array with values parsed from POST request. It can be assigned it can be overriden it can be cleaned. Just simple array. You won't modify POST request data but you'll override value in array.

Comment: Is the POST request data preserved elsewhere?

Comment: Yes it is for example in `$_REQUEST`